# Django Static Files not Loading on Heroku, GCS deployment

Tags: django, heroku, google-cloud-storage

So, I have created a django application and deployed it with Heroku. Static files (as well as media) are served by a GCS bucket.

I am currently having a problem loading *all* of my static files.  Notably, the png files are not loading, but everything else is.  The png file requests return a 403 error, but the rest of the files (css, js, etc.) load fine.
Furthermore, jpg images that were uploaded via media are returned without error.

I have to assume that this is a GCS problem, but I'm not entirely sure of that. I have tried everything in including assigning permissions to my service agent, creating another service agent, and recreating another bucket with the same data.

I have not had this problem when using GCS buckets with applications running on Google App Engine or GKE.

Any point in the right direction would be great.

This is the relevant part of my settings file.  Note that I put the `django_heroku.settings(locals())` call above this block of code intentionally, because it overrides these settings.

```
DEBUG = False

django_heroku.settings(locals())

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'hello-world'
GCS_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/'
STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/static/'.format(GCS_URL, GS_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = '{}/{}/media/'.format(GCS_URL, GS_BUCKET_NAME)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

UPLOAD_ROOT = 'media/uploads/'
```

Comment: 403 errors are usually due to permissions, this makes me think that the account that you are using in order to access the files may not have permissions to the troublesome png but does have permissions to the rest.

Can you test this by making a test with the png file set as public? This would allow us to identify if this indeed the reason of the issue

Comment: When I wget the png as is, I get a 403.  However, I get a 403 when wgeting other files that the web app accesses with no problems. When I make the bucket public, this problem goes away, which indicates that it is indeed a permissions problem. When I assign the storage object viewer permissions to my service agent, it lacks permissions again

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The files that were missing were being called from the CSS file (background images, etc).  Since they weren't being called with the `{% static %}` tag, the appropriate signatures weren't being added onto the call, and the bucket was seeing an unauthorized attempt to access the files.

My solution was to move these calls to bucket files inline, so that I could use the static tag.